# Copying Images to the UIPasteboard

Tags: iphone

How can one copy images to the UIPasteboard?

I have only seen examples for text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at [Apple's Documentation for UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPasteboard/image), you see that you can use the 'setImage:` method to copy images to the pasteboard, eg:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:myImage];
```

or if you want to add multiple images:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myFirstImage, mySecondImage, nil]];
```

or if you already have the array of images:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImages:myImagesArray];
```

(where all the above variables that begin with `my` should be substituted for the ones in your code)

Comment: Hey Can You Show Me Any Demo how to implement

Comment: i have all methos with me but i dont know how to implement

Comment: You Have Any Demo From Implemenation.

Answer (score 1):

use this ..... here newImage is UIImage.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:UIPasteboardNameGeneral create:NO];
pasteBoard.persistent = YES;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];     
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:00"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can just simply use these code:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = @"my string";
pasteboard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my image"];
```