# How to copy UIImage data to clipboard/UIPasteboard? And how do I test it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, copy-paste, uipasteboard

I tried to use the following code to copy the Image data to `UIPasteboard` on click of the Copy item in the menu.

```
UIPasteboard *gpBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[[gpBoard setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgView.image, 1.0) forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardTypeListImage];
```

Which parameter i have to send for `forPasteboardType`:, and how to test after copying the data?

Comment: This link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111422/copying-images-to-the-uipasteboard.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a lot easier:

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = imgView.image;
```

To get the image out again:

```
UIImage *image = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, how do i test? should i get the image out and set it to some ImageView?

Comment: @pradeepa You can open iMessage or whatsapp or facebook Messenger and paste the image. If you see your copied image then its done ^_^

Comment: I'm not seeing it get pasted, I'm trying to paste it to a UITextView, anything I gotta set for it?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above and for some reason it's a hit and miss on iOS 7,8. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't i.e. system doesn't show "Paste" option.

This worked for me consistenly on all devices and all iOS

```
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]);
    [pasteboard setData:imgData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = imageToCopy
```